# Why I can't see the table I create in python, in pgAdmin

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql

I created a table using psycopg2 in jupyter notebook.
This was done successfully and I didn't get any error. Now I want to see the table in the pgAdmin interface, but it doesn't appear there. Why?

This is the code I have written:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import Error
try:
    connection = psycopg2.connect(user = "postgres",
                                  password = "nadav256",
                                  port = "5432",
                                  database = "postgres")
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    create_table_query = '''CREATE TABLE demo2
          (ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
          TIME           VARCHAR(50),
          ACCABS         REAL,
          BARO           REAL); '''

    cursor.execute(create_table_query)
    connection.commit()
    print("Table created successfully in PostgreSQL ")
except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error :
    print ("Error while creating PostgreSQL table", error)
finally:
    #closing database connection.
        if(connection):
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
            print("PostgreSQL connection is closed")
```

This is the output I get:

```
Table created successfully in PostgreSQL 
PostgreSQL connection is closed
```

Comment: You looking in the right schema? You sure the table was actually created, as you don't actually try to access it from your code? I don't know how it works from python, but it seems surprising to use a cursor for a table creation statement. You sure that works as you expect?

Comment: can you add 
cursor.execute("select * from demo2")
print(cursor.fetchall())
in the end of the try part